# Edge Detection with Sobel Masks in Matlab this code is not accepting below mentioned line

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Edge Detection with Sobel Masks in Matlab this code is not accepting below mentioned line

this code is giving error at             res = maskx.*bwsquare;

i have watched step by step tutorial on the internet but still its not accepting this line

```
clear
clc
close all
origional = imread('q1jjy.png');
rubic = origional(:,1:500,:);

figure()
imshow(rubic)


bw= uint8((1/3)*(double(rubic(:,:,1))+double(rubic(:,:,2))+double(rubic(:,:,3))));
figure()
imshow(bw)

bwdbl = double(bw); 
figure()

maskx = [-1 -2 -1, 0 0 0, 1 2 1 ];
[r,c] = size(bw);
OUT = zeros(r-3, c-3);

for idx = 1:(r-3)
    for jdx = 1:(c-3)
        bwsquare = bwdbl(idx:(idx+2), jdx:(jdx+2));
        res = maskx.*bwsquare;
        OUT(idx,jdx)=sum(sum(res));
    end
end
Gx= OUT;
figure()
imshow(Gx)

masky = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1];
for idx = 1:(r-3)
    for jdx = 1:(c-3)
        bwsquare = bwdbl(idx:(idx+2), jdx:(jdx+2));
        res = masky.*bwsquare;
        OUT(idx,jdx)=sum(sum(res));
    end
end

Gy = OUT;
figure()
imshow(Gy);

G = sqrt(Gxdbl.^2 + Gydbl.^2);

figure()
imshow(G);
```

Comment: Your definition of `maskx` does not seem to be correct. Try replacing `,` with `;` to make a 3x3 mask. It would also have been helpful if you had posted the actual error message you received.

Comment: "its not accepting this line" is not a useful problem statement. You should always copy-paste the full error message into your question.